# Saving dictionary of tweets into JSON file results in an empty dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, twitter, dictionary

I am trying to collect some localized tweets and store them on my hard drive as a dictionary of tweets. In some iterations in the `fetchsamples` function, the saved dictionary is forced into empty state despite the fact that during the for loop data is added into the dictionary (see output below).

I have tried different encodings or passing "w" and "wb" flags to my save function but it didn't help.

I tried reproducing this using random strings (to allow people easier checking of my code) but I was unable to. I am unsure what in the tweet structure or my code is causing this behaviour.

NOTE: I have added a code snippet to catch when the dictionary is forced into empty state for debugging.

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib2 as urllib
import json
import pickle
import os

api_key = "Insert api_key here"
api_secret = "Insert api_secret here"
access_token_key = "Insert access_token_key"
access_token_secret = "Insert access_token_secret"

_debug = 0

oauth_token    = oauth.Token(key=access_token_key, secret=access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

http_method = "GET"

http_handler  = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)

def twitterreq(url, method, parameters):
    req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                                token=oauth_token,
                                                http_method=http_method,
                                                http_url=url, 
                                                parameters=parameters)

    req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)
    headers = req.to_header()

    if http_method == "POST":
        encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
    else:
        encoded_post_data = None
        url = req.to_url()

    opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
    opener.add_handler(http_handler)
    opener.add_handler(https_handler)

    response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

    return response

def fetchsamples():

    url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"
    url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?locations=-0.489,51.28,0.236,51.686"
    parameters = []
    response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)

    data = {}
    count = 1
    for line in response:        
        try:
            strip = json.loads(line.strip())
            if strip['coordinates'] != None:
                data[count] = strip

                count += 1

                if count % 10 == 0: 
                    print count, len(data.keys())

        except Exception as e:
            # Print error and store in a log file
            print e            
            with open("/Temp/Data/error.log","w") as log:
                log.write(str(e))

        # If 100 tweets have passed save the file
        if count % 100 == 0:
            print "Before saving: ", len(data.keys())
            fp =  open("/Temp/Data/"+str(count/100)+".json","w")
            json.dump(data,fp,encoding="latin-1")
            fp.close()

            # This code is for debug purposes to catch when dictionary
            # when dictionary is forced into empty state
            if os.path.getsize("/Temp/Data/"+str(count/100)+".json") < 10:
                print "After saving: ", len(data.keys())
                return data
            else:
                data = {}

data = fetchsamples()
```

This produces the following output with no error. The `data` dictionary is empty.

```
100 99
Before saving:  99
110 10
120 20
130 30
140 40
150 50
160 60
170 70
180 80
190 90
200 100
Before saving:  100
Before saving:  0
After saving:  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way I incremented the `count` value. Since `count` is incremented only when `strip["coordinates"] != None` if I receive a tweet where `strip["coordinates"] == None` the count value does not get incremented but `data = {}` and `count % 100 == 0` gives `True`, which means the original non-empty file is replaced with an empty one.

The solution is to increment `count` after saving such as here:

```
    if count % 100 == 0:
        print "Before saving: ", len(data.keys())
        fp =  open("/Temp/Data/"+str(count/100)+".json","w")
        json.dump(data,fp,encoding="latin-1")
        fp.close()

        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary is empty because after each 100 iterations, you either set data={} or the dictionary is already empty. If i understand correctly, you would need another dictionary, one which you never empty, and push items to that dictionary also.

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib2 as urllib
import json
import pickle
import os

api_key = "Insert api_key here"
api_secret = "Insert api_secret here"
access_token_key = "Insert access_token_key"
access_token_secret = "Insert access_token_secret"

_debug = 0

oauth_token    = oauth.Token(key=access_token_key, secret=access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

http_method = "GET"

http_handler  = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)

def twitterreq(url, method, parameters):
    req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                                token=oauth_token,
                                                http_method=http_method,
                                                http_url=url, 
                                                parameters=parameters)

    req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)
    headers = req.to_header()

    if http_method == "POST":
        encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
    else:
        encoded_post_data = None
        url = req.to_url()

    opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
    opener.add_handler(http_handler)
    opener.add_handler(https_handler)

    response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

    return response

def fetchsamples():

    url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"
    url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?locations=-0.489,51.28,0.236,51.686"
    parameters = []
    response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)

    data = {}
    allData = {}
    count = 1
    for line in response:        
        try:
            strip = json.loads(line.strip())
            if strip['coordinates'] != None:
                data[count] = strip
                allData[count] = strip

                count += 1

                if count % 10 == 0: 
                    print count, len(data.keys())

        except Exception as e:
            # Print error and store in a log file
            print e            
            with open("/Temp/Data/error.log","w") as log:
                log.write(str(e))

        # If 100 tweets have passed save the file
        if count % 100 == 0:
            print "Before saving: ", len(data.keys())
            fp =  open("/Temp/Data/"+str(count/100)+".json","w")
            json.dump(data,fp,encoding="latin-1")
            fp.close()

            # Return data if the file is empty and stop
            if os.path.getsize("/Temp/Data/"+str(count/100)+".json") < 10:
                print "After saving: ", len(data.keys())
                return allData
            else:
                data = {}

data = fetchsamples()
```

Comment: The reason I want to empty my dictionary is for memory management reasons. So I need to find a way to empty the dictionary (after I saved its contents to the disk). Your solution wouldn't work because I would quickly run out of memory.